# Set and define variables inside CTE (With) and use them in another CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Is there any way to define a variable inside a WITH expression like this?

```
declare @Var1
declare @Var2;

With CTE as ( Select ...),
CTE2 as (select 
       CTE.Something,
       @Var1=(Select .. from CTE),
       @Var1=(Select .. from CTE)
    From CTE
)
Select * from CTE2
```

Comment: Actually after assigning values to the variable, why you are selecting `cte2` query. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @DarkRob because I want to use it in another CTE

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks like T-SQL.

In T-SQL, you can't return a result set and set variables value in the same select statement, cte or not.

**The following code is invalid in T-SQL:**

```
declare @Var1 int;

select someColumn,
       @var1 = someOtherColumn -- or a subquery or whatever
from someTable
```

And it would still be invalid if the `select` statement was a part of a common table expression.

Also, a common table expression must contain a select statement that returns a result set - so you can't do something like this:

```
with cte as
(
    select @var1 = someColumn
    from someTable
)
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is some thing else.

Comment: something else in what way?

Comment: Defined variables will be used in another CTE

Comment: the definition of a variable in t-sql is done with the `declare` keyword, not when setting it's value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can set a variable in a CTE

If you specify your requirements we might find better solution

However my suggestion is not to use CTE but go with temp table and work from there

```
declare @Var1
declare @Var2;

Select *
Into #TEMP
from MyTable

Select @var1 = col1,
       @var2 = col2
from #TEMP

Select *, @var1, @var2
from #TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `select` and `set` in single statement.

For your query you need to do this in 2 parts only. First to set your variable value. Second query to get the result record in table format.

```
declare @var int

--- First statement
; with cte as
(select ...)
select @var = (select .. from cte) 

--- second statement
; with cte as
(select ...)
, ct as (
select id, (select .. from cte) from cte
)
select * from ct
```

Although it is not required to set your variable value in the middle of your query.

You either get the values in variable or get the data in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the **WITH common_table_expression** says:

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  

<common_table_expression>::=  
    expression_name [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]  
    AS  
    ( CTE_query_definition )
```

And the **CTE_query_definition** is (emphasis mine):

> Specifies a SELECT statement whose result set populates the common
>   table expression. **The SELECT statement for CTE_query_definition must
>   meet the same requirements as for creating a view**, except a CTE cannot
>   define another CTE. For more information, see the Remarks section and
>   CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).

In a view you can't set variables, so you won't be able to set them in a CTE also.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate - you can use variables in a common table expression, you just can't set their values.

Comment: Correct, I meant setting them.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation of WITH CTE's is on [Microsoft SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
WITH [CTE2] AS
(
   SELECT dbo.yourFunction1(t.column_i) as var1
   , dbo.yourFunction2(t.column_j) as var2
   FROM dbo.[CTE] t
   WHERE yourFunctionX(t.column_p) = 100
     AND t.column_q IS NOT NULL 
);

declare @var1 varchar(500), @var2 varchar(500);
Select @var1 = t2.var1, @var2 = t2.var2 from [CTE2] t2;
```